# Paypal auto redirect after creating new user / paying without logging in

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

It's redirecting if a user already has a paypal account, but if they create a new account / pay by card it doesn't redirect and then in turn doesn't send out my invoice or deduct stock.

How are you guys doing your stock adjustment / invoicing? Do you need it to be auto redirecting or are you using something else that makes this happen as soon as the payment goes through?

Comment: if an user create an account on paypal ,he immediately doesn't eligible for making payment ...

Comment: Please explain what you mean...? I'm using a buy now button, and everything is working as expected (if they already have a paypal account and login when they click buy now button) but if they click buy now button and then need to sign up / click pay buy card instead of using an existing paypal account, it then doesn't auto redirect back to my website after the transaction has been made. It only happens when they don't have a paypal account, if they already have a paypal account it redirects after 10 seconds after the payment has been made.

Comment: Is there another way of getting confirmation of a payment without having to use auto redirect and PDT? It seems silly to have to rely on the user's browser redirecting to a URL with GET data. Why can't paypal talk to a URL that I specify each time a transaction comes through, and just send the transaction variables in POST to that URL so that way I don't encounter issues with pages not auto redirecting after payment has gone through on Paypal.